# Prevent rerendering of child component on input change

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a component in reactjs where i define 2 states input and resultlist(an array). My functionality is like, I will enter some input click on search, call an api, set search results in result list. Now my problem is my search result is very huge. Once resultlist is populated first time, then whenever I am typing input it is rerendering whole component on each keypress including resultlist which is lagging a lot. How to handle this issue.

I tried using usememo on resultlist but it is not working. I don't want my Child to rerender on every keyspress in input.

```js
const comp1 = () => {
    const [input, setinput] = useState('');
    const [resultlist, setresultlist] = useState([]);


    const fetchResult = () =>{
        fetch('some url') // returns a very long list of items(10k +)
        .then(res=>setresultlist(res));
    }

    return <>
        <input value={input} onChange={(e)=>setinput(e.target.value)}></input>
        <button oncClick={fetchResult}></button>
        <Child resultlist={resultlist} />
    </>
}

const Child = ({resultlist}) => {
    return <>
        {resultlist.map(element=><div>element</div>)}
    </>
}
```

Comment: Hi, please add the actual code, otherwise it makes helping you much harder

Comment: Please view this post, we cannot help you if you do not provide what you've tried till now.
the post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have added code, I can not think of anything new or very smart way which will help me avoid re-render.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```js
const Parent = () => {
    const [resultlist, setresultlist] = useState([]);
    
    return <>
        <comp1 setresultlist={setresultlist} />
        <Child resultlist={memoizedResultList} />
    </>
}

const comp1 = ({setresultlist}) => {
    const [input, setinput] = useState('');

    const fetchResult = () =>{
        fetch('some url') // returns a very long list of items(10k +)
        .then(res=>setresultlist(res));
    }

    return <>
        <input value={input} onChange={(e)=>setinput(e.target.value)}></input>
        <button oncClick={fetchResult}></button>
    </>
}

const Child = ({resultlist}) => {
    return <>
        {resultlist.map(element=><div>element</div>)}
    </>
}
```